# How to deal with the lack of `simd_packed_float3` in Swift

Tags: swift, simd, metal

There is no `simd_packed_float3` type in Swift.

Why it's a problem?

Consider this Metal struct:

```
struct Test{
    packed_float3 x;
    float y;
};
```

First of all, you can't calculate a buffer pointer to address the memory of `y`, since you can't do this:

```
MemoryLayout<simd_packed_float3>.size
```

(Not sure if `stride` makes sense with packed types, but anyway with simd types it always gives the same length as size on my devices)

You can't use `MemoryLayout<simd_float3>.size` either, since it will return 16 and not 12 like in architectures available to me for testing.

Second, if you need to write a packed_float3 value of `x` to the buffer you will need to write the three consecutive floats, but not a single simd type. Again, simd_float3 is not usable since it will write 0 into the forth word corrupting the memory of the next property in the struct (`y`).

So I've done this:

```
struct Float_3{
   var x: Float
   var y: Float
   var z: Float
}

typealias simd_packed_float3 = Float_3
```

It seems to be a functioning solution, but I'm not sure it's not a nasty thing to do...
What problems may I encounter with this approach, and how could I be sure that it won't break on some device that I don't have?

Comment: You are wrong about `simd_float3` size, it will be 16 everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering this following the answers I received on the [Swift forum](https://forums.swift.org/t/no-simd-packed-float3-in-swift/61227/3).

Turns out that someone in the Metal team at Apple has already thought of this problem and created the `MTLPacked` types exactly for the types that would have irregular sizes:

- [MTLPackedFloat3](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlpackedfloat3/)
- [MTLPackedFloat4x3](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlpackedfloat4x3)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a packed struct in your bridging header:

```
struct __attribute__((packed)) PackedFloat3 {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};
```

```
MemoryLayout<PackedFloat3>.size == 12
MemoryLayout<PackedFloat3>.stride == 12
```

By the way, `simd_float3` is 16 bytes everywhere, simd types have stricter alignment requirements.

You can also typedef it to `packed_float3` under `#ifndef #ifdef __METAL_VERSION__` to have the same spelling in Swift and MSL.

The reason to do it in bridging header instead of Swift is that you can use the same structs with same spelling in both shaders and Swift.

Comment: The issue is my package is Swift only, I pass the MSL code to library in a string. So I wanted to be sure that it's a good practice - to declare such a struct in Swift. On the other hand - I need it to behave like a genuine packed type in shaders, so ideally Metal should be unaware of any memory manipulations on the Swift side.

Comment: Well, if the `MemoryLayout.size` matches the `MemoryLayout.stride`, it's gonna work. I initially thought that the `Float_3` struct in your question would get padded to 16 bytes, but it has both `stride` and `size` at 12. I had the same problem and in the end, I just made a type and added a test to check that `stride` and `size` match so that I never lose that assumption (it had to be a test cause Swift doesn't have a `static_assert ` or something similar)

Comment: Seems to be the only way for now. Probably I should pitch the addition of simd_packed_float3 since all other packed types are there except this one(the only one that actually matters with it's size being 12).